# How to Get Access of Activity for Custom Object

Tags: custom-object

I got a requirement, that i need to make a activity in related list of each and every Custom object. Anyone have any idea how to achieve this.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Page Layout of each record of each custom object :

1. edit the lay out.
2. Go to related list .
3. Add two related list and those are **Activity History** and **Open Activities**

please refer the screenshot:

[image]

PS:  -Make sure while you creating the object there is field called **"Allow Activities"**, that should be checked, otherwise you won't be able to get those related list. please find the screenshot below : -

[image]